# cURL response different from when opened in a browser

Tags: php, curl

In one of my projects, I'm required to grab the header/footer content from an external URL. One of the URL (say it's https://example.com/header) is behaving oddly wherein the content coming back is not what is expected.

For example, if I open the said URL in a browser, the source code reveals (PS: this is devoid of any html,head,body tags which is how it should be):

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

However, when I call the same URL via cURL, the response becomes:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 25</li>
   <li>Item 100</li>
</ul>
```

Of course, I'm showing a very simplified form of the response but there is significant difference between them.

The code I'm using is:

```
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0); // $url is https, so had to use this
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0); // $url is https, so had to use this
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

$user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0'
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); // this line was originally not being used, but I tried adding this to see if it helps - but it did not

$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

return $html;
```

What I'm not sure is if this is something that can be fixed at my end or should I get in touch with the team who is managing those URLs?

Comment: how are you viewing the browser html? if you're using the DOM inspector to get the html, then you're viewing it post-javascript-modifications, is it possible that the differences you're seeing is because javascript modified the html? PHP doesn't run any of the javascript

Comment: Soure code is viewed via Right click->View source option. I don't think there is any javascript trimming involved because I verified by echoing the content right after the curl call (i.e. before having them displayed on my site)